# Microsoft Access database to FileMaker Pro

Tags: ms-access, export, filemaker

I have all my customer details in Microsoft Access. I want to transfer all this data to FileMaker Pro. I hope there is a way to do this. If so please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You have basically two options (without resorting to any third party tool, besides ODBC):

1. **Use intermediate "common import/export formats"**: Export data from all the different tables in Access in a format that FileMaker Pro can immediately import, then import the exported files from FileMaker. The safest format is normally CSV --comma separated values--; although it won't work with FileMaker if you have data with line-feeds or carriage-returns inside. You can also try Excel as an intermediate export format (with this format, you may have some limitation if you have long texts). Check: [Introduction to importing and exporting data (Access)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-importing-and-exporting-data-08422593-42dd-4e73-bdf1-4c21fc3aa1b0?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) and [Bringing data into FileMaker Pro - Overview and troubleshooting.](http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/13723/related/1)
2. **Direct import through ODBC**: Directly import the tables from FileMaker by means of an ODBC connection**. When you install Office, you normally get ODBC controllers installed by default, so, if you have Access installed in your computer, you're very likely to have ODBC controllers as well. [Make an ODBC connection to your Access database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kUYPqauyyo), and use it from within FileMaker to import your tables. Check [Querying an ODBC data source from FileMaker Pro](http://www.filemaker.com/help/12/fmp/html/odbc_ess.20.12.html).

FileMaker can import *table data* from Access (or other databases). It cannot import *table relationships* (or foreign key relationships) or *primary key definitions*, *null/not null constraints*, *index definitions* or *check constraints*. All these *metadata* you'll need to transfer "by hand". The Access database documenter can help you get most of it.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with joanolo regarding using ODBC - and both options are valid. I have a good bit of experience transferring data between FileMaker and Access with [FmPro Migrator](https://www.fmpromigrator.com/services/access_to_fmpro_service.html), and I always prefer to use ODBC. Sometimes I notice that common formats like CSV/TAB delimited files may cause the columns to get mixed up. And as he mentioned, long text can also be a problem for Excel spreadsheets. At one time, spreadsheets would silently truncate long fields - though I think this is less of a problem today. Since I am very conservative regarding transferring data, I always like to make a direct connection between databases.

Comment: You should disclose your relationship to the product you promote.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I am the developer of FmPro Migrator, so I deal with a lot of data transfer issues. (I thought that came thru with my account info linked to my icon).

Comment: Disclosure of a potential conflict of interest should not require people to click on links.